# Application in Appstore (submit with iOS 5) works with iOS 6 but in not when debug

Tags: ios, app-store

We create an application (in iOS 5) and upload to Appstore. After that, Apple release iOS 6 and my application still works well in iOS 6. But, when I use my old code (in my laptop) to build (target is iOS 5) and run in iOS 6, one features does not work. I debug and found that this is because of the orientation api change.

My customer concerns that why app in Appstore can work ok with iOS 6 but our application does not (although the codes are alike). I don't know how to explain this issue because they need a reference.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: if I understand your problem correctly, you should be able to fix the orientation issues by opening your project in Xcode (assuming you are using the 6.0 SDK) and opening your .xib file, then selecting the File Inspector tab and unchecking "use autolayout".

it worked for me!

Comment: Thank Basheer, I could fix this. My problem is explain how our code doesn't work but the Appstore version does. It's because of the Base SDK

Comment: if you follow the steps I mentioned above, you can probably make your code work even with base SDK 6.0. Good luck with your app anyways!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your base SDK is most likely the 6.0 SDK with the build target specified as iOS 5. "Base SDK" and "build target" are two different things.

Think of the SDK in this case as a layer between the operating system and your app. It looks like the 6.0 SDK behaves differently towards you than the 5.0 SDK. That can happen, and may not have to do anything with the operating system below.

Most likely, you will find that with the new SDK your app will not only fail on iOS 6 but also on iOS 5. So moving ahead with time, you should fix the problem with the 6.0 SDK.

However, it is not a concern for the version that you have currently available on the App Store.

Comment: Thank Bandara, I forgot the "Base SDK" as xcode 4.5 is only support sdk 6. I use the xcode 4.3.2 and it work well now.